# Fill in input form using value of another input and clear validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have below angular material code where email should be copied in username field. But the same is triggering validation error even the value is been copied in username field. Please help me how I can fix this

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" maxlength="75" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" />
  <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['email'].errors?.required"> Email address is required </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['email'].errors?.pattern"> Enter valid email address </mat-error>
  <mat-error
    *ngIf="
      !signUpForm.controls['email'].errors?.emailAvailable &&
      !signUpForm.controls['email'].errors?.pattern &&
      !signUpForm.controls['email'].errors?.required
    "
  >
    Email address is not available
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" autocomplete="new-password" [value]="userEmail" />
  <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['username'].errors?.required">Username is required.</mat-error>
  <mat-error
    *ngIf="
      !signUpForm.controls['username'].errors?.usernameAvailable && !signUpForm.controls['username'].errors?.required
    "
  >
    Username is not available.</mat-error
  >
  <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['username'].errors?.space">Username cannot contain any spaces.</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['username'].errors?.maxlength">
    Username must be at most 50 character(s) long.</mat-error
  >
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you format the template, share the ".ts" code and the exact error too, please?

Comment: I have not added any code in .ts  to clear the validation if i fill username field from email field. If anything required to write in .ts let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your ts the options are not clear enough. However, see if `this.signUpForm.controls['email'].clearValidators();` can do the trick at the end of the method where you fill the email field from the ts (or where the this.userEmail gets its value).

Comment: I have not added any code in .ts  to clear the validation if i fill username field from email field. If anything required to write in .ts let me know